# Not able to Login website with Python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Please help me to login this website.
Website : http://www.staloysiuspuc.in/student_login.aspx
 I tried to login using requests in python

`<form method="post" action="./student_login.aspx" 
id="form1">`
This is the form
 My code is :

```
import requests

url = "http://www.staloysiuspuc.in/student_login.aspx"
payload = {
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtusername' : '*****',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtpass_1' : '*****',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtpass_2' : '*****',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtpass_3' : '*****'
}
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(url, data=payload)
print(r.url)
```

I get the same url again and again. It should be redirected to www.st ......... .com/student_profile
Please help

Comment: I masked the real data with asterisks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with ASP.NET sites/forms you need to also provide the obligatory hidden Postback inputs, namely:

- `__EVENTTARGET`
- `__EVENTARGUMENT`
- `__VIEWSTATE`
- `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR`
- `__EVENTVALIDATION`

These can be found as `input`s of `type="hidden"`. My suggestion is to grab these hidden variables using the `BeautifulSoup4` module ([link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)), which provides a relatively simple method for obtaining elements from a webpage. Others would opt for the `re` ([Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)) method, which is a bit more rudamentary, but many like it for its ability to get the job done quick and with no added external dependencies.

Anyway, once you have those hidden values you would include those in your payload along with what you already have.

To understand how I've arrived here, you can look at the source code and you'll notice the `__doPostBack` function in multiple places like this one:

```
function EnterEvent(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 13){ 
        __doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogin', "");
    }
}
```

**What does this mean?**
This means you'll need to supply the appropriate `__EVENTTARGET` & `__EVENTARGUMENT`  to the function, when sending the data, dependent on the action you're performing.

**How do I figure out the appropriate values for these two variables?**
For that we look at the Login button's source code:

```
<a id="lnkstlogin" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$lnkstlogin&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Login</a>
```

Here you'll see the appropriate values for these two variables that you need to pass in order for the login to be successful.

```
__EVENTTARGET = ctl00$lnkstlogin # and if that fails you can try the default value  ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogin  
__EVENTARGUMENT = '' # Empty String`
```

## Full, working code

```
# python3.7
# pip install requests BeautifulSoup4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = 'http://www.staloysiuspuc.in/student_login.aspx'

sess = requests.Session()
params = {
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtusername' : '***',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtpass_1' : '***',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtpass_2' : '***',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtpass_3' : '***'
}

"""
Step 1: GET page, so Session stores cookies & so we can grab the needed values to postback
"""
resp = sess.get(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

# Step 2: Add the discussed parameters
params['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogin'   
params['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = ''
params['__VIEWSTATE'] = soup.find('input', id='__VIEWSTATE')['value']
params['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = soup.find('input', id='__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')['value']
params['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = soup.find('input', id='__EVENTVALIDATION')['value']

# Step 3: Make the POST request
resp = sess.post(page, data=params)
# resp.url should be the url you said we'd be redirected to
print(resp.url)
```

Comment: Thank u very much sir for the answer. I understood some things. I wrote the code. If u have time can u send me the full code, just to verify.

Comment: When I get near a desktop I'll write out a full example for you, but I won't be able to test it since it requires your login info. Also, a side note make sure to request (GET) the URL before posting to it. This way the `requests.Session` will have any other cookies and referer info it needs to properly mimic a browser login.

Comment: Ok, Fine . I tried adding those two variable in the payload. But not working.

Comment: @Manjunath please see my edit for the full working code.

Comment: I hope this helps you & gives you an idea of what to look for. APS.NET/APSX sites are certainly very intimidating when first starting out with scraping because there are extra steps that aren't typically required of a non-ASPX form/site. Don't worry, we've all been there  Gotta start somewhere. Anyway, just a friendly reminder, if this solution worked for you please remember to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked for me.Thanks for the help. I was trying this from many days. Thank u.